# My cat is a bit scared of me

Tags: cats

My cat and i have an amazing relationship honestly. He loves me and i love him. Alot.

But, i suffer with well anger issues and i often yell or scream when I snap. (I'd like to clarify I dont scream or yell at him). I've never hit him or done anything that will scare him. Maybe raise my voice at him when he's doing something wrong but that's as far as it ever goes.

After one of my 'outbursts' he gets a little scared of me. He doesn't run away from me but does flinch when I touch him, he still likes to come and cuddle with me but is scared as he approaches me. I don't want him to stop trusting me and i have been careful not to snap in front of him but are there any tips on how i comfort him?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about OP needing counseling on anger management. This is not about a problem related to a pet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find a quieter channel for your anger issues, which is far beyond the scope of Pets.SE.

Your cat is always going to associate loud noises with danger because that’s an instinctive response in all animals with hearing—and the louder the noise, the more threatening it is, because louder noises usually come from larger animals.

On top of that, cats’ hearing is many times more sensitive than ours, so if you’re yelling loudly enough, it may be physically painful to him.  So, he’s going to be scared that you’re going to continue hurting him until he can tell you’ve calmed down.

Worse, since you also yell when he’s misbehaving, he’s going to be confused because he’s being punished even when he isn’t doing anything obviously wrong.  Any animal that is randomly hurt like this is going to develop severe anxiety about their powerlessness to stop the abuse.

Please get professional help for both your sakes.